# Mapping multidimensional array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrayobject

I need to recreate a multidimensional array of objects only by looking at a single node.

I tried using recursive function in a loop(Array.map).

```
obj = [{
  key: 0,
  children: [{
    key: 1,
    children: [{
      key: 2,
      children: [{
        key: 3,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 4,
        children: []
      }]
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      children: [{
        key: 6,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 7,
        children: [] 
      },
      {
        key: 8,
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

```
function test(arg, level=0, arry=[]){

  arg.map((data, i) => {
    if(!data.arry){
      arry.push(data.key);
      data.arry = arry;
    }
    if(data.children){
      test(data.children, level+1, data.arry);
    }
  })
}

test(obj);
```

Function *test* should build and return exactly the same object as *obj*. 
This is only a simplified version of the problem I have and that's why it looks weird(returning an object I already have). My original problem is about fetching parts of n-dimensional array of objects from DB but without knowing its original dimensions. So I have to "discover" the dimensions and then build the exact same copy of the object.

Comment: you can use a variant of DFS to do so. I'll add an example

Comment: please add the wanted result, or the input. this is not clear, what you want.

Comment: Function test should build and return exactly the same object as *obj* but only looking at a single node. You can imagine it only having first node of obj and then fetching it by using key property. When all nodes and children are discovered they should be glued together to form full object. 
The glueing part is where is my problem. Do I have to build some kind of map of each node position and then recreate it using the map?

Comment: The key fetching thing is still unclear to me. I'll post solution assuming we run until there are no more children for a given node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example implementation would be this: Recursively iterating over array and objects and deep-copying their properties/children. This creates a deep copy of an object, and tests that data is actually copied and not a reference anymore:

```js
 

   obj = [{
    key: 0,
    children: [{
        key: 1,
        children: [{
            key: 2,
            children: [{
                key: 3,
                children: []
            },
                {
                    key: 4,
                    children: []
                }]
        },
            {
                key: 5,
                children: [{
                    key: 6,
                    children: []
                },
                    {
                        key: 7,
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: 8,
                        children: []
                    }]
            }]
    }]
}];

function copy(obj) {
    let copiedObject;

    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        // for arrays: deep-copy every child
        copiedObject = [];
        for (const child of obj) {
            copiedObject.push(copy(child));
        }
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        // for objects: deep-copy every property
        copiedObject = {};
        for (const key in obj) {
            copiedObject[key] = copy(obj[key]);
        }
    } else {
        // for primitives: copy the value
        return obj;
    }

    return copiedObject;
}

function test() {
    const cpy = copy(obj);

    // make sure that deep-copying worked
    console.log('Values from obj should be exactly copied to cpy: ' + (cpy[0].children[0].children[0].key === obj[0].children[0].children[0].key));

    // make sure that references are broken, so that when data from the original object is updated, the updates do
    // NOT reflect on the copy
    obj[0].children[0].children[0].key = Math.random();
    console.log('Changes to obj should not reflect on cpy: ' + (cpy[0].children[0].children[0].key !== obj[0].children[0].children[0].key));
}


test();
```